# From selenium, how to find value locate by id?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium. I need to find a price display on a web page - 199. I am able to locate the element by

```
total_value = driver.find_element_by_id('items_total')
```

the html code is

```
<div class="quantity-value-total" id = "items_total">$199.00</div> == $0.
```

Is my line

```
total_value = driver.find_element_by_id('items_total')
```

assign the value of 199 to total value?  Please help

Comment: attach sample html code snip for element you trying also consider to attach code you wrote as part of question in order to increase chance of getting answer

Comment: What is the programming language you're using? You should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, the line

```
total_value = driver.find_element_by_id('items_total')
```

will not assign the value 199 to `total_value`. Instead it will assign an *object* (HTML element), whose *text* is `$199.00`. So you get that text using `text` property:

```
total_value = driver.find_element_by_id('items_total').text
```

Note that `total_value` will contain the full string (`$199.00`), so you will need to manipulate it if you just want to get `199` as a number

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use

```
String total_value= driver.findElement(By.id("items_total")).getText();
```

which will store the value `$199.00` in a string `total_value`